# Can't Connect Node MCU esp8266 to Thingspeak

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Flowmeter-NodeMcu-Counting-Litres/).  I am also using a same Node MCU ESP8266.  Ii connected it to my home network.  The local ip address is also displayed but it doesn't connected to my thingspeak channel and it stuck at the waiting for the client.

I also checked that my thingspeak API is correct and my home network is also working.

[image]

Comment: `192.168.43.40` doesn't look like an internet IP address that ThingSpeak would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Arduino IDE to program the NodeMCU. If this is the case, then all you have to do create a WiFiClient, then construct an HTTP POST request, and send it to ThingSpeak using the client.

Here are the relevant lines from my [tutorial](http://nothans.com/measure-wi-fi-signal-levels-with-the-esp8266-and-thingspeak):

Before your setup add the lines:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
WiFiClient client;
const char* server = "api.thingspeak.com";
String writeAPIKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

In your loop, add the following lines to read A0 and send it to ThingSpeak:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

    // Measure Analog Input (A0)
    int valueA0 = analogRead(A0);

    // Construct API request body
    String body = "field1=";
           body += String(valueA0);

    Serial.print("A0: ");
    Serial.println(valueA0); 

    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: " + writeAPIKey + "\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(body.length());
    client.print("\n\n");
    client.print(body);
    client.print("\n\n");

}
client.stop();

// wait 20 seconds and post again
delay(20000);
```

Comment: There is also an official [ThingSpeak Communication Library for Arduino and ESP8266](https://github.com/mathworks/thingspeak-arduino).  It wraps the details of the HTTP calls and parameter formatting and it provides some additional functions.  I used it in one of my projects.

Comment: Given a try to the answer below ? Tested an working.

Answer (score 0):

Use ESP8266HTTPClient HTTP lib to post to ThingSpeak via ESP8266. Here is an example function. Call it with a data parameter to write into your ThingSpeak channel:

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define TSPEAK_HOST       "http://api.thingspeak.com"
#define TSPEAK_API_KEY    "YOUR_THINGSPEAK_API_KEY"
#define LEN_HTTP_PATH_MAX 256

HTTPClient http;

unsigned short postThingSpeak(char* data)
{
  boolean httpCode = 0;
  char httpPath[LEN_HTTP_PATH_MAX];
  memset(httpPath, 0, LEN_HTTP_PATH_MAX);
  snprintf(httpPath, LEN_HTTP_PATH_MAX, "%s/update?api_key=%s&field1=%s", TSPEAK_HOST, TSPEAK_API_KEY, data);
  Serial.printf("Path to post : %s\n", httpPath);

  http.begin(httpPath);
  httpCode = http.GET();

  Serial.printf("Return  : %d\n", httpCode);
  Serial.printf("Incoming Body : %s\n", http.getString().c_str());
  http.end();

  return httpCode;
}
```